# Is runnin' an elision or assimilation?

Tags: phonology

Considering the word "running", would "runnin'" be the result of the **elision or assimilation** of the "ing" sound?

Specifically /ˈrʌnɪŋ/ being pronounced as /rʌnen/

---

I believe it's the assimilation, as the actual "ing" sound is partially retained

Comment: Are you asking about the written form, or the pronunciation it tries to represent?

Comment: To be clear, are you talking about the pronunciation /ˈɹʌnɪŋ/ being realized as something like [ˈɻʌnən]? Where would there be any sort of elision happening here? After all, no sounds have been skipped. As for assimilation, are you proposing regressive assimilation with some later phonological attribute like devoicing moving right-to-left as in *have to* becoming [ˈhæftə]? Or are you proposing progressive assimilation with some earlier attribute now instead moving left-to-right so that it affects something later in the word's pronunciation like *that is* /ˈðætɪz/ becoming [ðæts]?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty None of these terms make any sense in writing. Only pronunciation counts.

Comment: @tchrist, yes the pronunciation. Specifically /ˈrʌnɪŋ/ being pronounced as /rʌnen/. I'm not sure what you mean by regressive assimilation and devoicing, as I am new to this. - Added to question

Comment: It depends on whether people typically pronounce -ing verb forms /ɪn/ or not. If you say "sittin'", "walkin'", "playin'" and "runnin'", then it's a dialect feature.

Comment: "Losing the G" means using a dental instead of velar nasal finally. I'd say it was assimilation; there's no phonological reason to velarize a final nasal, and if it's always understandable unvelarized, that's enough reason right there. Make it a mark of the upper class, and the G's drop everywhere.

Comment: Elision means gliding into the next word or sound: like Long Island pronounced as Lawn Guylind. Not here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s not straightforward to explain the variation between [ŋ] and [n] in this context. It doesn’t occur after stressed vowels (e.g. in *sing, ring, rung, fang, wrong*), and nearly all the cases involve one specific suffix, the ending *-ing* (exceptions, for some speakers, are *nothing, something, pudding*). Based on the limited occurrence, it seems possible it might just be lexical variation rather than a phonologically motivated process.

I would not call it either assimilation or elision.

However, if you take the view that word-final [ŋ], although not phonetically a cluster, is phonologically derived from a cluster /ng/, then the change to [n] would constitute elision: the loss of the consonant phoneme /g/.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that view? Do scholars tend to take that view? Is the present participle ending in English 'ing'  historically in Germanic a consonant cluster /n/ or /ŋ/ followed by /g/?

Comment: @Mitch: I remember writing some more about this topic in response to previous questions. Here is one: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/361756/why-does-ing-go-to-in-in-some-dialects

Comment: Doesn't that other question make this a duplicate?

Comment: @Mitch: Maybe so. The other question doesn't bring up the topic of assimilation.